# Differing behaviours of JSONFormatter and XmlFormatter in ASP.net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Reduced down to its simplest form, I have a class that inherits from another

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected int _property1;
    public virtual int Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return _property1;
        }
        set
        {
            _property1 = value;
        }
    }

    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override int Property1
    {
        set
        {
            _property1 = value + 1;
        }
    }

    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

And a WebAPI controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/test/5
    public InheritedClass Get(int id)
    {
        return new InheritedClass
        {
            Property1 = id + 1,
            Property2 = id,
            Property3 = id - 1
        };
    }
}
```

If I request XML from the controller, with `GET api/test/1`, I get the data I expect

```
<InheritedClass>
    <Property1>3</Property1>
    <Property2>1</Property2>
    <Property3>0</Property3>    
</InheritedClass>
```

but if I request JSON, it omits the inherited property.

```
{"Property3":0,"Property2":1}
```

What I want is

```
{"Property1":3, "Property3":0, "Property2":1}
```

I can fix it by changing InheritedClass to

```
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override int Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return _property1;
        }           
        set
        {
            _property1 = value + 1;
        }
    }

   ...
```

But I don't really want to - that seems rather WET. What gives? Is there a setting on the JSONFormatter I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Json serialization by using the `Formatters.JsonFormatter` of your `HttpConfiguration` object.

By configuring the `DefaultContractResolver` to search for public, non public and instance properties explicitly, you can fix the behavior you are seeing.

You can do this by adding the following code to your `WebApiConfig.cs` file in the `App_Start` folder:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
     {
         DefaultMembersSearchFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
     };
```

Comment: Thanks - Close, but no cigar... This gives `{"_property1":3,"Property3":0,"Property2":1}` so it looks promising.  It seems as if the `JsonFormatter` is setting `DeclaredOnly` by default?